# Working with node and ejs. Why might <%= no be recognised inside quotes "", no colour change

Tags: node.js, ejs

The issue is on the 3rd row below. With in the href""'s, there is text and an a js script syntax, <%=. for some reason, the <%= is not being recognised as a script insert.

Any idea's on why this is happening and how to fix? I'm using node.js, Express, MongoDB, Mongoose

```
                <% if(users.length > 0) {  %>
                    <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
                        <a href="/getUsers/<%= user._id %>">
                            <tr>
                                <td><%= user.userId %></td>
                                <td><%= user.userName %></td>
                                <td><%= user.userOperator %></td>
                                <td><%= user.userEmail %></td>
                                <td><%= user.userMobile %></td>
                                <td><%= user.userAdminYN %></td>
                            </tr>
                        </a>
                    <% }) %>
                <% }else{ %>
```

I tried adding the script syntax in, and was expecting to see it change colour as it does elsewhere in the core.

Comment: Is the code not working as expected or is it a syntax highlighting issue?

Comment: both, I'm following an online course, working with node.js and express for the first time. all is going fine until I got to this point. I've looked back at all the code and I can't see anything different to what is in the examples. the code is in an .ejs file

Answer (score 0):

Use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<a href="<%= `/getUsers/${user._id}` %>">
```

Comment: thanks for that .. I tried you suggestion. The same thing, I'd expect the code to change colour at the $ sigh, but it stays the same colour as the rest of the string text. It does not seem to be recognising the special character inside the quote signs. very confusing ..

Comment: Ah, I understand. So, it's more a problem related to your IDE?

Comment: Thanks. for coming back to me. I think it's something to do with the set up. I'm working with node.js and express for the first time. I think the issue may be to do with how I set up the app. Im following an online course and this is working in the examples, but not for me and I can't see anything I've done differently to the examples.

Comment: To be sure: it's about syntax highlighting? The code itself works fine? What IDE do you use?